# Fair Ranking of Ratings Based on Number of Votes

Tags: algorithms

I'm attempting to take a list of products and rank them according to rating and votes. This is tricky!

Lets suppose product **A** is rated at average **5.6** at **310** votes. Product **B** is average **7.3** at **10** votes. Product **C** is **3.4** at 1 vote.

Product **B** has hardly earned a winning place with 10 votes, but product **A** is lesser rated with a much bigger voting base, showing it's persistence. Product **C** shouldn't be ranked poorly just because one (possibly ignorant) user is pissed at it. Maybe it's new to the market - much newer than product **A**.

I was hoping to find the most reasonable "modifier" to get them to rank according to earned position.

Perhaps just a small modifier? `Votes/Rating` to distinguish them?

Comment: There isn't mathematical question here. You can divide or multiply, eliminate the lowest and highest scores, compare medians or means... Nothing will change the fact that the data is grossly lacking, and we don't know which product is better.

Comment: Perhaps confidence intervals, treating the votes as if they were random samples, would create the appearance of "objectivity".  The problem is that voting is anything but a random sample.

Comment: What is the rating scale? Tell me that and I will give you an answer.